# How to store and get a array values in cookie with Angular version 1.5

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, cookies, setcookie

I need to push value in array and stored in cookies when user click on GO button.

if value is more than 10 i need to remove the first added item in the array and updated cookies , displayed in front end.

but i'm tried multiple ways some time i am getting values sometimes not , the code is not consistently working.

please find below the code

```
var cookieName = 'orderList';
$scope.orderList = $cookies.getObject(cookieName) || [];
$scope.saveCookie = function (val) {
    if ($scope.orderList.length >= 10) {
      $scope.orderList.shift();
    }

    $scope.orderList.push({productName: val}); 
    $scope.orderList = $cookies.putObject(cookieName,$scope.orderList);
  }
```

Note : I am using angular 1.5 and cookie 1.5 version .and i am getting console error .

http://plnkr.co/edit/K17uJv72U2ytG6JHZBtn?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't realize one thing. The error only appears when you click the button the second time.
The reason why you're getting this error is the last line in your code-

`$scope.orderList = $cookies.putObject(cookieName,$scope.orderList);`

when you replace it with -

`console.log(typeof $cookies.putObject(cookieName,$scope.orderList));`

you'll get `undefined` in the console. And that is the catch. When the function runs the second time, it is evaluating `length` of `undefined`, and hence, the error.

Just replace the line with `$cookies.putObject(cookieName,$scope.orderList)`, because your `$scope.orderList` is already equal to the array with the new value pushed.

**EDIT:**
**Updated Code**

```
var cookieName = 'orderList';
$scope.saveCookie = function (val) {
    $scope.orderList = $cookies.getObject(cookieName) || [];
    if ($scope.orderList.length >= 10) {
      $scope.orderList.shift();
    }

    $scope.orderList.push({productName: val}); 
    $cookies.putObject(cookieName,$scope.orderList);
}
```

I brought the definition of `$scope.orderList` inside the function, since, in case the value of it is lost, it will reevaluate on each button click. Its not crucial in all cases. You might keep it out of the function, depending on your application flow.

Comment: can i remove the last line ??

Comment: @CodeMan you mean removing completely? That is your wish. But then the value of `cookieName` won't be equal to `orderList`.

Comment: @CodeMan did it. please see.

Comment: @ Ritik Saxena  : Thanks !!!..your code is perfectly working in plunker . when i am integrate in my page most of the times cookie value not set in browsers.but some times i am able to see cookie values in browsers.Then what is the issue ?? you have any idea??

Comment: @CodeMan add `console.log($cookies.getObject(cookieName))` wherever you are using the value and see if it is available in the console. The code you've provided isn't enough to debug this new issue. It might be a browser issue too.

Comment: @CodeMan please accept the answer if it solved the issue of throwing errors in the console. :)